# Jenkins - "Text Finder Plugin" responding "file is empty "

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I had installed "Text Finder Plugin" in my Jenkins.
Then provided the url of the file on which jenkins should search.
even-though there is the file in the location it is giving me the following output

```
Jenkins Text Finder: File set '%WORKSPACE%\*.html' is empty
```

It is showing the same output if the file actually doesn't exist also.
I had tried with all the solutions available but couldn't succeed. 
Is there any configuration before using this plugin in jenkins.

Comment: Are you sure, the file path is correct and valid? I'm using the TextFinder plugin v1.10 and it works well. I had a similar issue, where in fact I was looking for the log file _before_ it was renamed! Thus it wasn't available at the time the plugin was looking for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd like to provide the way we sorted out this issue, so that it can be useful for someone indeed. Follow the below steps:

1.Print the contents of the file from the jenkins job(just "Cat filename" will work), so the content will be printed on the jenkins console output

2.Use this plugin to search in the console output(by enabling "search in console output" option,it works well in this case) instead of directly from file